Polars when().then(map_elements(function)) always calls function
I have this code:
import polars as pl

def get_year(entry_id: str) -> str:
    arr = entry_id.split('.')
    print(f'> Function is called for {entry_id} <')
    if arr[0] != 'DEBT':
        return None
    else:
        return int(arr[1])

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'Type': ['CAT_YY', 'CAT5', 'CAT_YY', 'CATX'],
    'ID':   ['DEBT.24', 'CASH.EU', 'DEBT.26', 'CASH.US'],
}).with_columns(year=pl.when(pl.col('Type') == 'CAT_YY')
                       .then(pl.col('ID').map_elements(get_year, return_dtype=pl.Int64))
                       .otherwise(None))

print(df)

which gives the correct result (= strip out the YY part year from the ID, if the Type is CAT_YY).
shape: (4, 3)
┌────────┬─────────┬──────┐
│ Type   ┆ ID      ┆ year │
│ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---  │
│ str    ┆ str     ┆ i64  │
╞════════╪═════════╪══════╡
│ CAT_YY ┆ DEBT.24 ┆ 24   │
│ CAT5   ┆ CASH.EU ┆ null │
│ CAT_YY ┆ DEBT.26 ┆ 26   │
│ CATX   ┆ CASH.US ┆ null │
└────────┴─────────┴──────┘

However, my function get_year gets called for every entry in my dataframe, regardless of the pl.when(...) condition:
> Function is called for DEBT.24 <
> Function is called for CASH.EU <
> Function is called for DEBT.26 <
> Function is called for CASH.US <

I am very surprised by this, because this seems counter-intuitive & also very inefficient. Note, in practice, my data and my function are a lot more complex. So this is just a toy example to demonstrate the issue.
Am I doing anything wrong? How can I change polars logic to only call get_year when the pl.when() condition is actually satisfied?

.when() always executes all then/otherwise branches. There is a warning in the docs:

Polars computes all expressions passed to when-then-otherwise in parallel and filters afterwards.

You can change to .when().then().map_elements()
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col('Type') == 'CAT_YY')
      .then(pl.col('ID'))
      .map_elements(get_year, return_dtype=pl.Int64)
      .alias('year')
)

> Function is called for DEBT.24 <
> Function is called for DEBT.26 <

It works in this case as map_elements() has a skip_nulls= parameter (which defaults to True).

Further info
This topic has cropped up many times on the Github issues - many people have found this behaviour surprising.
Relevant feature request with discussion:

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/17601

The Polars author replied as to why it works this way:

"I don't want to go into the details, but all of this would be terrible expensive and therefore not a direction I want to go in."


Since map_elements is a loop, you can apply the condition in it. The power of when/then would make sense if you have fast vectorial expressions:
def get_year(entry_id: str) -> str:
    arr = entry_id.split('.')
    print(f'> Function is called for {entry_id} <')
    if arr[0] != 'DEBT':
        return None
    else:
        return int(arr[1])

df.with_columns(pl.struct(pl.col('Type'), pl.col('ID'))
                  .map_elements(lambda x: get_year(x['ID'])
                                          if x['Type']=='CAT_YY'
                                          else None,
                                return_dtype=pl.Int64
                               )
                  .alias('year')
               )

This is similar to using numpy.where vs a list comprehension with an inner test. Note that you can use a list comprehension:
df.with_columns(year=[get_year(i) if t=='CAT_YY' else None
                      for t, i in zip(df['Type'], df['ID'])])

Output:
> Function is called for DEBT.24 <
> Function is called for DEBT.26 <
shape: (4, 3)
┌────────┬─────────┬──────┐
│ Type   ┆ ID      ┆ year │
│ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---  │
│ str    ┆ str     ┆ i64  │
╞════════╪═════════╪══════╡
│ CAT_YY ┆ DEBT.24 ┆ 24   │
│ CAT5   ┆ CASH.EU ┆ null │
│ CAT_YY ┆ DEBT.26 ┆ 26   │
│ CATX   ┆ CASH.US ┆ null │
└────────┴─────────┴──────┘


Unless this is pedagogical, you don't need map_elements. You can use built-in string functions:
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "Type": ["CAT_YY", "CAT5", "CAT_YY", "CATX"],
        "ID": ["DEBT.24", "CASH.EU", "DEBT.26", "CASH.US"],
    }
).with_columns(
    year=pl.when(pl.col("Type") == "CAT_YY").then(
        pl.col("ID").str.extract(r"\w+\.(\d+)").cast(pl.Int64)
    )
)

df

shape: (4, 3)
┌────────┬─────────┬──────┐
│ Type   ┆ ID      ┆ year │
│ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---  │
│ str    ┆ str     ┆ i64  │
╞════════╪═════════╪══════╡
│ CAT_YY ┆ DEBT.24 ┆ 24   │
│ CAT5   ┆ CASH.EU ┆ null │
│ CAT_YY ┆ DEBT.26 ┆ 26   │
│ CATX   ┆ CASH.US ┆ null │
└────────┴─────────┴──────┘


Assuming @BallpointBen and @jqurious's solutions don't work for some other case, (for instance if different conditions mean running a different python only function) a more general workaround is to partition the df by the condition and then concatting them back together.
df = pl.concat([
    _df.with_columns(year=pl.col('ID').map_elements(get_year, return_dtype=pl.Int64)) 
    if i[0]=='CAT_YY' else 
    _df.with_columns(year=pl.lit(None, pl.Int64))
    for i, _df in df.group_by('Type')
])

This has the side effect of rearranging the original order so if the order is important you have to handle that explicitly by adding a row index first and then sorting by it last like this
df = pl.concat([
    _df.with_columns(year=pl.col('ID').map_elements(get_year, return_dtype=pl.Int64)) 
    if i[0]=='CAT_YY' else 
    _df.with_columns(year=pl.lit(None, pl.Int64))
    for i, _df in df.with_row_index('i').group_by('Type')
]).sort('i').drop('i')

